# unable to get the current location in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile

unble to get the current location in jquery mobile using jquery google map plugin

Following is my code but i am not getting any current location data
i have tried two different ways but its not working don't know why , what i am getting is the 
center pan map.

**code #2 is based on this [example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map)**

> var mobileDemo = { 'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 10 };

Code #1

```
$('#findme_map').live("pageshow", function(e,d) {
          console.log("findme_map<map> of pageshow");

                        //$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'getCurrentPosition');
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center});
                         $('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(status, position) {
                        if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                                        $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)});
                                console.log("values",position.coords.latitude+ ','+position.coords.longitude);
                        } else {
                                    console.log("unable to find the location"); 
                        }
                });


         });
```

Code #2

```
$('#findme_map').live("pagecreate", function(e,d) {



$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center, 
         'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 
         'disableDefaultUI':true, 
         'callback': function() {           

         var self = this;

         self.set('getCurrentPosition', function() {
         self.refresh();
         self.getCurrentPosition( function(position, status) {                                                                                              console.log("sef set", status); 
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.coords.latitude, 
                position.coords.longitude);
                self.get('map').panTo(latlng);
                self.search({ 'location': latlng }, function(results, status) {

                    if ( status === 'OK' ) {

                                console.log("return", results[0].formatted_address);    



                    }

                }); //sefl.search
            }// status==OK first one
            else{

                console.log("unable to find the location"); 
            }


            }); // self.getCurrentPosition



        }); //sef.set



        }
    }); <!-- end of gmap -->

});
```